# Get same formating under netbeans and eclipse

Tags: eclipse, netbeans

I use eclipse and netbeans, I was most able to have similar formatting, except for a few thing.

Under eclipse i get

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/secure/admin/json/user", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
```

Under netbeans i get

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/secure/admin/json/user", method =
{
    RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET
})
```

Is there a way to get the same thing under netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Eclipse formatter plugin.

See https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/eclipse_java_code_formatter_in